# Swagger UI is showing "null" for "Example Value" for every API endpoint of our application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm not very familiar with the backend of our application, but am trying to investigate why our all of our endpoints are missing "example values" on our app's Swagger page.

We're not confident when exactly this started occurring, but they were definitely ALL present a few weeks ago.

How might I proceed next in trying to understand why this may be happening?

There haven't been any obvious modifications to our project dependencies, swagger configuration, etc. I checked our recent MRs and *I think* the only thing that was changed in anything having to do with swagger was the addition of a @Qualifier annotation to an Autowiring of "RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping", although I don't know anything about it.

I understand all of this isn't a lot of information, but I don't know what I don't know. I will try my best to respond to questions for further information.

I saw a lot of mentions of "Springfox" when googling about this issue but I don't believe we use this, as searches for this term in our code come up null.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you give some detail about your code setup, dependencies, and configuration?

Comment: @Yserbius, thank you for your response. I'm glad to say that upgrading our springdoc version from 1.6.3 to 1.7.0 fixed it. I wouldn't have known what to tell you, so I'm glad it's fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved after upgrading the spring doc version from 1.6.3 to 1.7.0.